# Pass data to view and return to controler

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list of items and I want to move by them with 2 buttons next and previus.

this it´s my model:

```
 public class Pedido 
{ 
    public int Pos { get; set; } 
    .................. 
}
```

the controler:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
    { 
        Pedido ped = new Pedido(); 
        ped.Pos = 2; 
        return View(ped); 
    } 

    [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult Index(Pedido p) 
    { 
        p.Pos++; 
        return View(p); 
    }
```

and the view:

```
<form method="post"> 
@Html.Hidden("Pos", Model.Pos) 
@Model.Pos     
<input type="submit" value="Sig" />
</form>
```

When I run application, view shows "2" (@Html.Pos=2) and hidden field value =2 (OK). I press button sig. @Html.Pos=3 and hidden value =2 why?. Next time I click button param "p" in httlpost action p.Pos=2

how can solve it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solve it:
ModelState.Remove("Pos")

Answer (score 0):

You're POSTing back two separate fields, try this instead:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Pos)
@Model.Pos
```

To bind your hidden input properly to your `Pos` property.